# Massive amounts of "Empty file." in GitHub Pull-request changes-tab

Tags: git, github, pull-request

### A brief take on the Situation

Hay,
I'm working on a student Project with some others and have found a recent problem after looking through a Pull Request change-log from myself and noticing that there were 211 Files changed even tho I'm 100% sure that I did not in fact change that many files.
After looking a bit closer (and with that I mean scrolling through the changes) I saw [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHLEj.png).

(The Files listed in the Picture are just a small part. It's actually quite a number of Files that seem to be listed like that as well)

The only Explanation I have is that this happened after a pull from the main branch to update the one I am now trying a PR from now.

The Files in question still seem to exist fine without any changes made to them or having been deleted.

### Now my Question is...

...how can I prevent this from happening? I did use the visual Git-Tools provided by the Jetbrains IDE RubyMine, since it's more intuitive for merge conflict resolves.